# Pure CSS: unlimited nesting accordion?

Tags: html, css, accordion

Is there a way to create a pure CSS and html unlimited nesting accordion? I have below as a base but when I try to nest an accordion within an accordion it doesn't seem to work. For example,

Main Accordion

- Subaccordion1
      Content for subaccordion1
- Subaccordion2
      Content for subaccordion2

I would like the main accordion to contain both subaccordions 1 and 2. When I added a second accordion to the main accordion either the main accordion would not contain the second one or subaccordion2 would become indented one level lower than subaccordion1 when I tried different ways to moving the code so far.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
 
<head>
 <meta charset='UTF-8'>
 
 <title>Notes</title>
 
  <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .box { display: block; }
        #box { overflow: hidden;position: relative; }
        b { position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width:1px; height: 251px; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -9999px; }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
 
<body>
 <!-- Styles for collapsible list -->
 <style>
  .collapsibleList li > input + * {
   display: none;
  }

  .collapsibleList li > input:checked + * {
   display: block;
  }

  .collapsibleList li > input {
   display: none;
  }

  .collapsibleList label {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
 </style>
 <!-- Styles for collapsible list -->
    
<!-- Content start here -->
    <!-- Main Accordion start -->
    <ul class="collapsibleList">
    <li>
    <label for="mylist-node1"><font color="#2c84fc"><u>Main Accordion</u></font></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node1" />
        
        
        <!-- subaccordions start -->
            <!-- Subaccordion1 start -->
            <ul class="collapsibleList">
            <li>
            <label for="mylist-node2"><font color="#2c84fc"><u>Subaccordion1</u></font></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node2" />
                <ul>
                <li>Subaccordion 1 content
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- subaccordion1 end -->
            
            <!-- Subaccordion2 start -->
            <ul class="collapsibleList">
            <li>
            <label for="mylist-node3"><font color="#2c84fc"><u>Subaccordion2</u></font></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node3" />
                <ul>
                <li>Subaccordion 2 content
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- subaccordion2 end -->
        
        <!-- sub accordions end -->
        
        
    </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Main Accordion end -->
<!-- Content end here -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [Adjacent selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). This selects only the immediate sibling.

```
input + *
input:checked + *
```

You can change that to a [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). That should select all siblings at the same level.

```
input ~ *
input:checked ~ *
```